# Anyone get working FTPS/FTP::TLS Under Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, ssl, ftps

I've tried several gems, examples, etc, and cannot get this working, the more promising gems were: [double-bag-ftps](https://github.com/bnix/double-bag-ftps) and [FTPFXP](https://github.com/square/ftpfxp), I can connect but I cannot transfer files, in active or passive mode..

sample code with ftpfxp:

```
@conn2 = Net::FTPFXPTLS.new
@conn2.passive = true
@conn2.debug_mode = true
@conn2.connect('192.168.0.2', 990)
@conn2.login('myuser2', 'mypass2')
@conn2.chdir('/')
@conn2.get("data.txt")
@conn2.close
```

sample code with double-bag:

```
ftps = DoubleBagFTPS.new
ftps.ssl_context = DoubleBagFTPS.create_ssl_context(:verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
ftps.connect('192.168.0.2')
ftps.login('myuser2', 'mypass2')
ftps.chdir('/')
ftps.get("data.txt")
ftps.close
```

sample error with double-bag:

```
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/double-bag-ftps-0.1.0/lib/double_bag_ftps.rb:148:in `connect': Broken pipe - SSL_connect (Errno::EPIPE)
```

Sample error with ftpfxp:

```
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:206:in `initialize': No route to host - connect(2) (Errno::EHOSTUNREACH)
```

Any recomendation that does not involve external commands ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue, the server was returning a private ip address while trying to connect in pasive mode with Explicit tls, so I've added a line to Double-Bag-FTPS to check if the returned ip was private fallback to the original public ip address...

[GitHub Pull request](https://github.com/bnix/double-bag-ftps/pull/3)

So if someone has the same issue maybe this is the answer hope that this can help someone else :)